# Example of Heine-Borel Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

For a subset $S$ of Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$,

> S is closed and bounded if and only if
>   S is compact (that is, every open cover of $S$ has a finite subcover).

I need an example or application of this theorem to understand it well. Could you please give one?

Comment: $\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots,0\}$ is closed (why?) and bounded. The theorem then tells us that it is compact. Without using the theorem, can you prove that it is compact? (Consider an open cover.) Perhaps it is useful to draw what this space looks like, as well as potential open covers.

Comment: On the other hand, $[0,1)$ is not closed. Can you provide an open cover with no finite subcover? $[0,\infty)$ is not bounded. Can you show it's also not compact?

Answer (score 1):

The Heine-Borel theorem plays a crucial role in the development of both Riemann and Lebesgue integration on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Perhaps the most important result in Riemann integration is that continuous functions on closed intervals $[a,b]$ are integrable. The reason is that $[a,b]$ is compact by Heine-Borel, so continuous functions on it are uniformly continuous, and uniformly continuous functions are well approximated by their value at finitely many points.

In Lebesgue integration, the Heine-Borel theorem is the fundamental fact about geometry of Euclidean space that makes a lot of the crucial lemmas work. For instance, the Lebesgue measure of a closed interval $[a,b]$ had better be $b-a$. If you look at the definition of the Lebesgue measure, you'll see it has to do with countable coverings of sets, and the Heine-Borel theorem allows us to replace those countable coverings of $[a,b]$ with finite ones. That's what makes the proof work.

It's also important in the proof of the mean value theorem. When you prove Rolle's theorem, you need the fact that a continuous function on $[a,b]$ attains both a maximum and a minimum.

Comment: To add, It is also useful to show that two spaces are not homeomorphic to each other. For example, Heine-Borel tells us that the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is compact. Then, we can say that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not homeomorphic to the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ since continuous functions preserve compact sets, and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open!